Classifying All Random Variables
I just wish to check whether I'm right or wrong regarding the follow categorization of random variables. $\def\W{\Omega} \def\FFF\mathcal{F}$

Definition: a random variable $X$ is a measurable function $(\W,\FFF,P)\to(\W',\FFF')$ from a probability triple to a measurable space.
We say $X$ is finite, (infinitely) countable, or uncountable iff the smallest (cardinallity-wise) set $K$ for which $P(X\in K)$ is finite, countable, or uncountable, respectively.
We further say $X$ is discrete, continuous, discontinuous, absolutely continuous, or partially continuous iff so is its cumulative distribution function $F$, where, to clarify

$F$ is discrete iff it is a step (simple) function i.e. there are constants $\{c_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and sets $\{E_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such tht
$$F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty{c_k}1_{E_k}(x).$$
$F$ is partially continuous iff it is continuous, but not absolutely so.


The Categorization:


The reasoning behind it: a random variable has a simple step function for $F$ if and only if there is a countable (finite or countably infinite) set $K$ for which $P(X\in K)=1$; thus they are either finite or countable. As simple step functions are discontinuous, so are all discrete random variables. Therefore the only continuous random variables must be the uncountable ones. By definition, uncountable random variables clearly split into continuous and discountinuous, while the former clearly splits into absolutely and partially continuous.

I am not sure what the purpose of this is. Mathematics is not Biology. What is a "partially continuous" function? Edit: I saw you defined it. Totally trivial.

@KurtG. It's fair that it is of no interest to you. In my case though, I spent some time wondering how the set of all absolutely continuous and the set of all discrete RVs relate to each other i.e. can they intersect? do they exhaust all possibilities? The current post can be viewed as an answer to all such questions.

Take a CDF that has a few jumps and is otherwise strictly increasing. Is a RV with that CDF not discrete and continuous at the same time? Socratic question. I only want to highlight that trying to express every mathematical fact with single words is not only not of interest it is also rarely successful.
